# How to connect to Oracle Database from Visual Studio 2022 for creating EDMX

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g

I am using Visual Studio 2019.
Our project is using Oracle database (ODAC 11g Release 2) and .NET framework 4.5.2

Since couple years, we are using Oracle.DataAccess.dll in service project. We are generating connection string manually by concatenating all settings of database before making connection in our API.
Connection settings contains HOST, PORT, SERVICE_NAME, User Id and Password.

Now we want to use Entity Framework. Problem is when I try to add new connection, I don't see options to choose TNS Type, Service name settings

I am expecting below popup,
[image]

I am getting below popup,
[image]

Questions is,
Do I require to install any tools related to ODP.net?
And if yes, then will it automatically take care on client server machine while deployment or same tools need to install on client server too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you are using VS 2019 or VS 2022. The title says one version and the text in the question says another:

If VS 2022:
You need to install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2022:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OracleCorporation.OracleDeveloperToolsForVisualStudio2022

If VS 2019:
You need to install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2022:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OracleCorporation.OracleDeveloperToolsForVisualStudio2019